# Chrome Animations button missing

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, css-animations

I'm trying to find a way to debug my CSS animations in Chrome specifically. I downloaded the latest version of Chrome Canary since it was supposed to contain this feature. Multiple sources confirm that there should be a button in the DevTools under the style tab.

[image]

However, the button is simply not there. It's also not available in the most recent version of regular Chrome, or in the Chrome a colleague of mine uses. Is there some setting I'm missing?

It's very hard to find a good source for this problem, that's why I'm asking you guys for help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why there's no button, but you can open the animation tool by selecting it from the context menu in the console drawer.

[image: chrome devtools animations]

Comment: This was a major help! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

My chrome version is 61 and the animation button is now moved to "More tools" under the 3 dots to the top right. Hope my answer can help those who view this post recently.

[image]

Comment: hope someday there will be opportunity to put it alongside whith Elements, Console and other main tabs.